# Search Criteria Form

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

So I've managed to get my criteria form up and going in access, and it searchs Name/City , but it only searches for the EXACT city name, even though ive given it a wildcard, and the name field works as a search any part of the field? Anyone know why? here is my code:

```
 'Text field example. Use quotes around the value in the string.
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterCity) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([City] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterCity & "*"") AND "
    End If

    'Another text field example. Use Like to find anywhere in the field.
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterMainName) Then
        strWhere = strWhere & "([MainName] Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterMainName & "*"") AND "
    End If
```

Thanks!

Comment: @Colin, have you checked the final value of `strWhere` -- is there another part that's masking the City filter?

Comment: Doesn't there end up being a trailing `AND ` in `strWhere`? If so, how does that not screw things up? Did you know that "And" means "Duck" in Danish?

Comment: Ah! yes you're all correct, it trails with AND
([City] = "Salt") AND 
([City] = "Salt") AND 

^ when searching for salt lake city - Let me fix this really quick, will respond.

Comment: So does anyone have any idea how I could write this to create a new search box for States, that allows the user to Input a state code like FL and have the results come up, if I had a field that has full state names? :)

Thanks for all the help thus far!

Comment: @Colin: Post this as a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a different approach to building strWhere.

```
' Text field example. Use quotes around the value in the string. '
If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterCity) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND City Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterCity & "*"""
End If
' Another text field example. Use Like to find anywhere in the field. '
If Not IsNull(Me.txtFilterMainName) Then
    strWhere = strWhere & " AND MainName Like ""*" & Me.txtFilterMainName & "*"""
End If
' chop off leading AND '
strWhere = Mid(strWhere, 6)
Debug.Print strWhere
```

I discarded the parentheses and square brackets because they weren't needed here.  Square brackets surrounding a field name are needed if the field name includes spaces, punctuation characters, etc.  Square brackets are also useful if the field name is a reserved word.  I prefer to use only characters which don't require bracketing in object names, and [avoid reserved words](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) as object names.

Comment: Thanks a ton for this HansUp! :) You've been really great at anwsering my questions, and providing assistance. Your time and effort are appriciated greatly.

Answer (score -1):

if you are using access then

* allows you to match any string of any length (including zero length)

? allows you to match on a single character

# allows you to match on a single numeric digit

eg:

Like 'b*'   would return all values that start with b

Like '*b*'    would return all values that contain b

Like '*b'   would return all values that end with b

Like 'b?'   would return all values that start with b and are 2 characters in length

Like 'b#'   would return all values that start with b and are 2 characters in length where the second character is a number